# Can Airport Extreme have a separate network using XBrand modem connectted via Ethernet

Tags: network, airport, ethernet

I have recently added solar to my home. There is a monitoring system to monitor the panels inverter via a wireless connection to their gateway that connects via Ethernet to my Airport Extreme router. I would like to setup that Ethernet connection so it is secure from my home network but is able to send the required information that it is supposed to provide to the Solar Companies' portal. Is there a way of providing this separate access either via another router or directly via my Airport Extreme?

Comment: What exactly is the end goal here? That if someone were to access the wired connection via the inverter, that they would not be able to access your physical network still? Or, is there something else in mind?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an Airport Extreme with a [guest network](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204590) {Apple.com}. This is entirely separate from your in-home network even though it runs on the Airport. In this case it would be kind of like setting up a home network 'DMZ' that keeps some services away from the main network at-large.